# Debug in eclipse not highlighting current line of code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When i'm debugging in eclipse, everything works as it should but there is just a minor problem. When debugging it does not highlight the current line of code or the next line of code. This is so frustrating, hope there is somebody out there that can help me with this problem.

Comment: It Looks like your source code do not fit to the cass fles. try to clean and rerun your project

Comment: Are you in the Debug perspective?

Comment: Find out where Eclipse _thinks_ you are.  You might be running a class in a jar file deep on your build path instead of what you think you are.

Comment: Debugging C code/C++/Java code?Share screenshot here http://imgur.com